# How to delete only one character from a repetitive string in python

Tags: python, string, duplicates

In a String, there can be duplicate characters present, but should be equal number of duplicate characters for each char. If not then try to make equal by deleting single only char

`abc` - Accepted as good String because a=1, b=1, c=1

`aabbcc` / `ababcc` / `abcabc` - Accepted as good String because a=2, b=2, c=2

`aabbcca` - In this case a=3, b=2, c=2, then delete last duplicate char of a and Accepted as good String because a=2, b=2, c=2

Examples:

input1 : `aabbccb`, output will be : `aabbcc` and Good String

input2 : `abcacbb`, output will be : `abcacb` because a=2, b=3, c=2 and Good String

input3 : `acbaabc`, output will be : `acbabc` because a=3, b=2, c=2  and Good String

Comment: Please show what you've tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: You forgot to include what you tried to solve it. Also, the rule is not quite clear to me – does the outlier always occur exactly one time too often? What would you expect to get for `abbccc` or `abccaccb`?

Comment: If every char must have 2 duplicates, you can just get the list of the chars and duplicate each char in output.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a dictionary of the characters in the string and their counts,then creates a new dictionary of the characters in the string and their counts, but only up to the minimum count of the characters in the first dictionary.

```
def is_valid(str):
    n = len(str)
    dd = {}
    for i in range(n):
        if str[i] in dd:
            dd[str[i]] += 1
        else:
            dd[str[i]] = 1

    diff_val_count = list(set(dd.values()))
    minimun = min(diff_val_count)
    new_dd = {}
    new_str = ""
    for i in range(n):
        if str[i] in new_dd and new_dd[str[i]] < minimun:
            new_dd[str[i]] += 1
            new_str += str[i]
        elif str[i] not in new_dd:
            new_dd[str[i]] = 1
            new_str += str[i]

    return new_str


print(is_valid(str))
```